# How can I modify a decision tree classifier to exclude unacceptable (feature, decision) pairs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am making a decision tree classifier in scikit-learn to recommend one of a set of medical treatments to patients based on clinical inputs. One treatment, call it no_epi, is contraindicated for any patient who has ever had epilepsy due to risk of injury, so these treatments cannot ever be suggested to an epilepsy patient, even if such a patient would otherwise be recommended them.

I worry that relying on the training set will not be enough to guarantee that the scenario epilepsy=True and decision=no_epi can never occur, and therefore I suspect it will be necessary to hard-code this into the tree after training. My first guess is to do this hard-coding by a kind of "reverse pruning" in which I would start with the deepest no_epi leaves and replace them by a subtree as in the following
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVtl9.png).

My question is two-fold:

1. Is anyone aware of a better way to do this than the reverse pruning method I sketched out?
2. How could I practically implement this reverse pruning in scikit-learn after training the tree on features other than epilepsy? I thought about manually modifying the attributes `children_left` and `children_right` of the `Tree` class, but I get the exception
   `AttributeError: attribute 'children_left' of 'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree' objects is not writable`

Thanks very much for the help, and happy holidays to all who celebrate!

Comment: I'm interested in your worry about the validity of your training data. If the class `no_epi` always occurs if `epilepsy=True` in the training set, then the presence of `epilepsy` is 100% predictive of the `no_epi`. The classifier will pick up on this. Have you observed otherwise?

Comment: The problem is that epilepsy is a rare condition, only present in less than 5% of cases, and also the no_epi treatment is not often suggested. Therefore if I do automated pruning e.g. by setting the parameters max_depth or min_impurity_decrease or min_samples_leaf, there's a good chance that epilepsy will never be a relevant decision. This is not a bad thing as the only relevance of epilepsy is as a contraindication for the no_epi treatment, but it is a hard contraindication.